# Summary function for principal coordinates analysis

Tags: r

R function *prcomp()* for performing principal components analysis provides a handy *summary()* method which (as is expected) offers a summary of the results at a glance:

```
data(cars)
pca <- prcomp(cars)
summary(pca)

Importance of components:
                           PC1     PC2
Standard deviation     26.1252 3.08084
Proportion of Variance  0.9863 0.01372
Cumulative Proportion   0.9863 1.00000
```

I would like a similar summary for displaying the results of a principal coordinates analysis, usually performed using the *cmdscale()* function:

```
pco <- cmdscale(dist(cars), eig=TRUE)
```

But this function does not provide a summary() method and therefore there is no direct way of displaying the results as percent variances, etc.

Has anyone out there already developed some simple method for summarizing such results from PCO?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

With best regards,

Comment: Thanks, but it does not do: these functions also do not provide a summary() method. The vegan package also offers a wcmdscale() function which should have a summary() method, but does not have either.

Comment: print() also does not provides the properly required formatted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the basic `cmdscale`, one can use `capscale` or `dbRda` from package vegan instead. These functions generalize PCO as they "also perform unconstrained principal coordinates analysis, optionally using extended dissimilarities" (citation from ?capscale help page). This is much more than a workaround.

The following gives an example:

```r
library(vegan)

A <- data.frame(
  x = c(-2.48, -4.03, 1.15, 0.94, 5.33, 4.72),
  y = c(-3.92, -3.4, 0.92, 0.78, 3.44, 0.5),
  z = c(-1.11, -2.18, 0.21, 0.34, 1.74, 1.12)
)

pco <- capscale(dist(A) ~ 1) # uses euclidean distance
# or
pco <- capscale(A ~ 1)  # with same result


pco # shows some main results
summary(pco) # shows more  results, including eigenvalues
```

The summary function has several arguments, documented in `?summary.cca`. Parts of the result can be extracted and formated by the user, the eigenvalues for example with `pco$CA$eig`.

Comment: Thanks, this provides a good solution with a lot of informative output. I had already written a simple function for presenting the results of cmdscale() in a format identical to that generated by prcomp(), but the output of capscale() seems more detailed.